# list of Font File (.ttf format) for supported iphone font name?

Tags: iphone

Hi is anyone have idea . from where i can get the list of font file (.ttf ) for supported iphone font name. some font file i have found in macOs Lib.but i need all font file . so any idea?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this information from the UIFont class. This will give you the true supported list of fonts.

```
NSArray *fontFamilies = [UIFont familyNames];
for(NSString *fontFam in fontFamilies) {
  NSArray *fontNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:fontFam];
  ... do whatever needed with the names
}
```

Comment: thans for reply . i am looking for actual font file like Helvetica.ttf. where can i get these file

Comment: Why would you need the file itself? You can't access those anyway on the iPhone.